# Remember what folders were collapsed / opened

Tags: xcode, expand, savestate, project-navigator

I have a big iOS-project with many folders / groups. When I quit and restart Xcode, all folders in the *Project Navigator* are shown expanded, so I have to collapse most of them manually.

Is it possible to save the state of the *Project Navigator*, so that when Xcode restarts the same folders are collapsed / expanded as before?

Comment: That is the default behaviour. Works fine for me in Xcode 5 - which version are you using?

Comment: 4 years later, this problem still plagues Xcode. Deleting `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` buys me a week or two at best until the bug resurfaces.

Comment: This is a bug and still unresolved. Please dupe the issue at  http://openradar.appspot.com/32787072 on http://bugreport.apple.com. Concerning that this has been unresolved for five years.

Answer (score 31):

The solution was to delete this file:

```
MyProjectName.xcodeproj > project.xcworkspace > xcuserdata > myusername.xcuserdatad > UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

This file was recreated by XCode when re-opening the project.

Apparently that file got corrupted when XCode crashed.
(Its size was 300 KB instead of the usual 10 KB).

To see the files right click on `MyProjectName.xcodeproj`, and choose *Show Package Contents*. You will find `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`in the subfiles.

Comment: What you mean delete file MyProjectName.xcodeproj > project.xcworkspace > ...? MyProjectName.xcodeproj and xcworkspace are files but not folders...

Answer (score 0):

1. Project Navigator > search file (enter a random sting), shows 'No Filter Results'.
2. Close project.
3. Reopen project.
4. All folders have been reset.

[image]