# Xcode Folders Auto-Expanding When Clicking "Project Navigator"

Tags: xcode

Every time I re-open the Project Navigator tab in the left side of Xcode (I.E move away from it into another tab and come back to it), my folders and subfolders all "magically" expand on their own. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. It's getting really frustrating collapsing them on my own every time (even with the option-*Arrow Key* short cut).

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: this is happening to me too! its so annoying. Im also searching for a solution

Comment: @user2464951 thought I was the only one! If I get a solution I'll update it here. For now, I been just closing all folders by highlight the top directory and holding option + left arrow key. But it's so frustrating still

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode remember what folders were collapsed / opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223633/xcode-remember-what-folders-were-collapsed-opened)

Comment: This is a bug and still unresolved. Please dupe the issue at  http://openradar.appspot.com/32787072 on http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Input any number of letters in the File filter, then close your Xcode immediately, then reopen your Xcode, then you will see the magic

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant - this should be the selected answer.  Forget deleting folders, just make sure you close all the folders and then type in the characters.  Then Quit Xcode , don't close the project - just quite Xcode.

Comment: Genius. Everyone, please file a quick bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com, you can just copy and paste the one from http://openradar.appspot.com/32787072. Apple often state that the more an issue is duplicated by people filing the same bug, the higher up the priority list it's moved.

Comment: It works but the problem comes back some time later :(

Answer (score 57):

I found a solution for this from another posted question.

Delete this file...

```
MyProjectName.xcodeproj > project.xcworkspace > xcuserdata > myusername.xcuserdatad > UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

[Xcode remember what folders were collapsed / opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223633/xcode-remember-what-folders-were-collapsed-opened)

I also had a similar issue with the search filter for an asset catalog failing to clear. Deleting the .xcuserstate file solved that as well

Comment: Sorry but after deleting this file, Xcode 9 keeps expanding all project folders e.g., when I add a new file or group to the tree. ¿Any ideas?. Even if I delete this file, and relaunch Xcode, all folders keep expanded. It's very annoying

Comment: To make this work on Xcode 9, I had to delete the entire myusername.xcuserdatad directory. Otherwise as @AaronWright said, it is only a temporary fix.

Comment: Deleted the file but still same issue

Answer (score 4):

With CocoaPods, delete this:

```
MyProjectName.xcworkspace > xcuserdata > myusername.xcuserdatad > UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Comment: I wasn't using CocoaPods, but I still had an .xcworkspace outside of the project directory and this was the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to click the square in the red circle. Maybe you accidentally clicked it without knowing that

[image: Screenshot from XCode]

Comment: this solution worked for me other solutions like deleting files etc didn't work

Answer (score 1):

In my case @G.Car... and @Younes Rouabah answers did not work alone. But both done the trick

Step 1: Delete File

```
MyProjectName.xcodeproj > project.xcworkspace > xcuserdata > myusername.xcuserdatad > UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Step 2: Restart XCode

Step 4: Click the square in the red circle

[image]

Restart XCode Again